# Program wont move past delete

Tags: c++

So I can not figure out why my program halts at the delete statement inside my purge loop. It's not crashing it just won't execute or give my any sort of error.

I have double checked that I am deleting an array and need the brackets, and verified that it is valid new memory. It will not work if its called by the destructor or explicitly

```
int main()
{
    darray DA1;
    DA1.Add("Hello");
    DA1.Add("Good Morning");

    return 0;
}

void Add(const char * string)
{
    char ** temp = new char *[m_count + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < m_count; ++i)
    temp[i] = m_array[i];
        temp[m_count] = new char[strlen(string)];
    strcpy(temp[m_count], string);
    delete[] m_array;
    m_array = temp;
    m_count++;
}

void Purge()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_count; ++i)
    {
        delete [] m_array[i];
        m_array[i] = nullptr;
    }
    delete[] m_array;
        m_array = nullptr;
    m_count = 0;
}
```

I expect it to go through the 2d dynamic array deleting each array and then delete the final array.

Comment: People asking for help here are required to post a minimal, reproducible example. The code in your question is neither minimal nor reproducible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These lines contain an error:

```
temp[m_count] = new char[strlen(string)];
strcpy(temp[m_count], string);
```

... in that you allocate `strlen(string)` bytes, but neglect to allocate the extra byte required for the NUL terminator required at the end of the string.  Thus your `strcpy()` command writes one byte past the end of your allocated array, invoking undefined behavior.  You can correct it by changing it to this:

```
temp[m_count] = new char[strlen(string)+1];
strcpy(temp[m_count], string);
```

One separate note:  manually managing heap-allocations this way is very difficult to get right, even for experienced programmers, so unless you are writing this program as an exercise in order to learn how to manually-manage heap-allocation, I highly recommend using `std::string` (or some similar string-class) instead of C-style char-arrays.  You will save yourself a lot of unnecessary pain.  (In fact, I think a `std::vector<std::string>` would provide you with all the functionality you are trying to implement here)